# Advanced OOP in PHP5?

Tags: php, oop, class

I want to know more about OOP in PHP 5.2.

Can anybody help me with a link to advanced OOP tutorials in PHP?

I know about `static`, `public` and `private` class member attributes, but I need more info about basic and advanced OO techniques. I hope somebody can help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked out the [OOP WikiBook entry](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Object_oriented_programming)?

Comment: Tanks, i print the Wiki page out, :) now i need samples. tanks of lot.

Answer (score 4):

In order to first understand OOP with PHP, you must understand the core concepts behind OOP. Tutorials won't help you correctly grasps things like abstraction, inheritance, encapsulation, and polymorphism.

Grab a book about Object Oriented Programming, that is the best way to learn. One of my favorites is:

## Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software

[image: Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software]

If you want something more PHP oriented, I heard nothing but good things about:

## PHP 5 Objects, Patterns, and Practice

[PHP 5 Objects, Patterns, and Practice http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51BF7MF03NL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg](http://www.amazon.com/)

Both are available at [Amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590593804)

I don't understand why so many young/new programmers have a total aversion for books when they start learning.

Comment: tanks for tip about the book, but that i need its links on the internet :) its "OOP tutorils" i need. :)

Comment: "I don't understand why so many young/new programmers have a total aversion for books when they start learning."  It seems as if all the books people recommend are always the most expensive ones.  $20ish for a book I don't mind, but $50 and upwards is kind of a lot.

Comment: **@nilamo:** Because it is those books that teach you the most.

Comment: **@NeoNmaN:** OOP Tutorials won't help you if you don't understand abstraction, inheritance, encapsulation, and polymorphism.

Comment: thats i men is i need to read about ( abstraction, inheritance, encapsulation, and polymorphism. ) like you say, don't in a book, becures i need to read it on internet and have PHP samples soe i can understand it better. :)

Comment: @Andrew Moore: I'm finding that out.  A lot of people recommended Steve Krug's Don't Make Me Think, and it's subject matter was aligned with my interests so I picked it up.  $40ish, but definitely worth it.

Comment: **@nilamo:** Oh yes! Great book! I've have it in my library. Very fast read, but extremely well written!

Comment: **@NeoNmaN:** I've modified my post to include a second book which is more PHP oriented. I've heard good things about that book. It will also teach you about OOP Concepts. Trust me when I say tutorials won't get you very far.

Comment: Or at least won't make you stand out of the crowd in the case of a PHP developer.

Comment: The design pattern book impacted my career so much.  It's a book I always have sitting next to my PC

Answer (score 0):

This is good: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/6/0/0